# Laravel 5.4 order by on multiple table's column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've to fetch record from two table by using JOIN.The record should come order by Date first and in that date record should be sorted by review column (both in desc order).

All work is done by raw queries and no relation or modals are defined (very outdated code). So what is the possible solution?

[image: Screenshot]

```
select `Feedback`.`FeedbackId`, `Feedback`.`SiteId`, `Feedback`.`MyTestimonial`, `Feedback`.`ReviewDate`,`Feedback`.`Overall` as `F_Overall`, `Feedback`.`Code`, `ProductFeedback`.`PID` as `ProductId`,`ProductFeedback`.`Product` as `ProductName`, `ProductFeedback`.`Rating`, `ProductFeedback`.`FeedbackId` as `ProductFeedbackId`, `ProductFeedback`.`Id` as `PF_Id`,   from `Products` as `Products`  inner join `ProductFeedback` as `ProductFeedback` on `Products`.`Id` = `ProductFeedback`.`PID` inner join `Feedback` as `Feedback` on `Feedback`.`FeedbackId` = `ProductFeedback`.`FeedbackId` where `ProductFeedback`.`Rating` > 0 order by `ReviewDate` desc, `ProductFeedback`.`Rating` desc limit 21 offset 0
```